# Where do I draw the line on formalness?

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy

I have been writing a mini fantasy story, and I wrote this line:

> Ironic, is it not, that the god of joy could never bring joy to themselves?

I'm not quite sure whether the 'is it not' and the question mark at the end restrict it from being formal enough. Is there a way I could write it better?

Comment: That's the same sentence as "Ironic, isn't it?" or "Isn't it ironic?", just rearranged. Your sentence is perfectly fine in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to be formal. The only requirement I'd say is that you want consistency, in the voice of the narrator.

If this line sounds out of place with the rest of the writing, then you have a problem. Otherwise it is fine. I've seen stories written with the narrator being a bumpkin, full of slang and colloquialism, but it was entertaining.

I wouldn't worry about formality, just consistency; it should not be surprising for the reader to read this tone or level of detachment.